# export c++ constructor using version script in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Suppose I have this simple C++ class:

```
//Myclass.h
class MyClass
{
    public:

    MyClass(char *cfgFile,int Num);
    void tfuuuuuuu1(double X);
    void tfuuuuuuu2(float X,float Y);

};
```

I want to export only the constructor `MyClass(char *cfgFile,int Num);` **using the `--version-script` option in gcc** (7.4.0 if that matters) so when I enter 
`$ nm -D --defined-only libMyLib.so` I will only see the constructor, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 0: use *actual* (or at least correct) code. The sample you gave wouldn't compile because `class Myclass` != `MyClass`.

Step 1: determine mangled name of the desired constructor:

```
nm -C libMyLib.so | grep '::MyClass'

000000000000111a T MyClass::MyClass(char*, int)
000000000000111a T MyClass::MyClass(char*, int)

nm  libMyLib.so | grep 111a
000000000000111a T _ZN7MyClassC1EPci
000000000000111a T _ZN7MyClassC2EPci
```

Step 2: write a linker script:

```
cat libMyLib.lds
FOO {
  global: _ZN7MyClassC2EPci;
  local: *;
};
```

Step 3: profit.

P.S. It might be easier to use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on the constructor and build with `-fvisibility=hidden` instead of using the version script.

Comment: thank you, (corrected my Q), BTW the `-fvisibility` simply don't work, `nm` still shows all the functions - this is why I am using version script. BTW, do you know why it looks like there are two constructors in the dump, and not one? I see the same thing with my code

Comment: @BennyK `-fvisibility` *does* work. Ask a separate question and I'll show you how.

Comment: `nm` lists the full symbol table. If you want to look at the _exported_ symbol table, you have to do `nm -D`.